# QlikView - adding a value to an average trendline

Tags: qlikview

I have a bar chart in QlikView and have added in an average line from `Properties > Expressions > Trendlines > Average`.

I want to display the value of this average, but not sure how...

Hope this is enough information, please let me know if not!

Answer (score 2):

You can display the "equation" for the trendline by selecting "Average" and then checking the box to the right marked "Show Equation":

[image: The Trendline Configuration Group]

This then results in a small piece of text added to your chart as follows:

[image: A chart with a trendline equation shown.]

Comment: Thanks. I think this option might only be available on line charts? I have a bar chart and I think the option to show equation is greyed out. Out of office now but can check after weekend.

Comment: @i_saw_drones Can you give this value a custom label instead of `y = xxx`